# Обновление схемы бд SQLite net 3.5

Tags: .net, sqlite

Как выполнить обновление схемы бд на стороне клиента в приложении net 3.5, использующем SQLite?

Я догадываюсь, что с помощью  скрипта. Но как этот скрипт выполнить при запуске приложения, или что-нибудь в этом роде?

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните, что Вы имеете в виду говоря "обновление схемы бд на стороне клиента"?

Comment: @Streletz , имеется ввиду, что появилась необходимость добавить новое поле в какую-либо таблицу. Да или просто, нужно добавить новую таблицу в рабочую бд у пользователя. Вот он работал, работал с моим приложением какое-то время. и тут изменились требования, нужна новая таблица в бд. как быть?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite позволяет производить [модифицию существующей таблицы](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Чтобы проверить, существует ли таблица, можно выполнить запрос

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';
```

Чтобы проверить, существует ли столбец в таблице, можно [запросить текущую схему](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) таблицы(получить все столбцы из таблицы)

```
PRAGMA table_info(table-name);
```

и проанализировать полученную информацию.

Комбинируя всеми этими возможностями, **как самый простой вариант**, можно вставить код модификации текущей схемы БД **при запуске приложения**. 
Например,

- вставлять столбец, если не существует его в таблице(анализируем схему и выполняем команду при необходимости `alter table mytable add column colnew char(50)`)
- [удалять таблицу, если она существует](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) (`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME`)
- [создавать таблицу, если не существует](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html:)(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (..)`)
- т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы добавить новую таблицу или изменить существующую необходимо выполнить SQL запрос `CREATE TABLE` или `ALTER TABLE` соответственно.

Если эти действия необходимо выполнить из Вашего приложения, реализуйте в нём отправку указанных запросов. В случае успешного выполнения можно спокойно обращаться к вновь созданным объектам.

Как-то так.